# Get links from string PHP

Tags: php, substring

I need a function that returns all links the videos in this string :

```
amf-editor|Joss Whedon||amf-img|<!--dle_image_begin:http://www.cpasbiens.eu/uploads/posts/2015-04/1430088868_avengers-age-of-ultrona.jpg&#124;--><img src="http://www.cpasbiens.eu/uploads/posts/2015-04/1430088868_avengers-age-of-ultrona.jpg" alt="AVENGERS: AGE OF ULTRON" title="AVENGERS: AGE OF ULTRON"  /><!--dle_image_end-->||amf-actor|Robert Downey Jr., Chris Evans, Mark Ruffalo||video1|http://videomega.tv/cdn.php?ref=048082108051120119074100048070070048100074119120051108082048&width=660&height=400||video2|https://openload.co/embed/_8xErAYN2yU/Avengers.Age.of.Ultron.2015.720p.BluRay.HD_%7C_www.onlinemovies.is_%7C.mp4||video3|http://vid.ag/embed-vxgzplvnegh8.html

For example :

$video1 = http://videomega.tv/cdn.php?  ref=048082108051120119074100048070070048100074119120051108082048&width=660&height=400

$video2 = https://openload.co/embed/_8xErAYN2yU/Avengers.Age.of.Ultron.2015.720p.BluRay.HD_%7C_www.onlinemovies.is_%7C.mp4

$video3 = http://vid.ag/embed-vxgzplvnegh8.html
```

Thank you

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: okey thank you Sahil Gulati

Answer (score 0):

This one line regex might be helpful.

```
function make_clickable($text) {
    $regex = '#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, function ($matches) {
        return $matches[0];
    }, $text);
}

make_clickable($video1);
```